# How to make "contact me" btn (located at component "Home.jsx") -- SCROLL TO -- "Contact details" section (located at component "Contact.jsx")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botón, scroll, component

Tengo:

--> "contact me" btn, ubicado en el componente "Home.jsx".

--> "Contact details" sección, ubicada en el componente "Contact.jsx"

Ambos componentes están añadidos en el DOM "App.jsx", pero no dentro uno de otro.

El propósito es que el botón "contact me" me mueva (smooth scroll) hasta la sección donde está "contact details".

**COMPONENTE Home.jsx** ==> Este es mi código:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
   import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
   
   const Home = () => {
     const transition = { type: 'spring', duration: 2 }
        
     const contactSection = useRef(null);
     const scrollDown = (ref) => {
            window.scrollTo({
              top: ref.current.offsetTop,
              behavior: 'smooth',
     });
   };
        
   return (
      <>
        <button className="btn_contact_me" onClick={() => scrollDown(contactSection)}>    
        </button>
      </>
    )
   }
        
   export default Home
```

**COMPONENTE Contact.jsx** ==> Este es mi código:

```
import React from 'react'


const Contact = () => {


 return (
    <div className='contact' id='contact'>
        <span className='title' ref={contactSection}>CONTACT DETAILS</span>
    </div>
 )
}

export default Contact
```

**Este es el ERROR:**

ERROR
[eslint]
src/components/Contact/Contact.jsx
Line 15:39:  'contactSection' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** He creado un nuevo componente *Scroll_button.jsx*:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';


function Scroll_button() {
    const handleScrollToContact = () => {
      const element = document.getElementById("contact");
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    };
  
    return (
      <button onClick={handleScrollToContact}>Contact</button>
    );
  }


export default Scroll_button
```

**2.** Luego, en mi componente *Home.jsx*, donde quería ubicar el botón "contact me", añadí:

```
import React from 'react'
import Scroll_button from '../Scroll_button/Scroll_button'

const Home = () => {

  return (
    <>
        <Scroll_button to="contact_me" /> 
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**3.** Por último, asegurarme de que el *Contact.jsx* contaba con su correspondiente id:

```
import React from 'react'


const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div id='contact' className='contact'></div>
  )
}

export default Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero te encuentres bien.

Te dejo el link de la respuesta, está en inglés y especifica exactamente lo que hay que hacer con respecto a los Ref, ya que al estar en el mismo App, no quiere decir que estos hablen entre sí o se conozcan, por eso el useRef de "react" te ayudará a que se puedan conectar y realizar interacciones entre ellos.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278497/how-to-scroll-to-a-component-from-another-component-in-react

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo he intentado pero, al no conocer bien cada parte del código, me sale que el componente no es una función.

He creado aparte un Scroll_btn como componente para que se pareciese más, pero ni así.

En el DOM está <Contact /> y <Home />, y el botón que tiene la funcionalidad está dentro de Home.jsx

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el contenido del enlace que proporcionas. Piénsalo: si alguien llega a tener un problema similar, se encuentra con tu respuesta, y el enlace está caído, ¿cómo podrá corroborar que la respuesta es útil? Lee [answer].